# WebotsController cannot read ros2_controllers generated from Moveit

Tags: ros2, moveit, webots

So, I have been trying to use a modified UR3e robot with Moveit in Webots simulation. The configurations are created by moveit setup assistant. I start from modifying the provided launch files from webots_ros2 github ([enter link description here](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots_ros2/tree/master/webots_ros2_universal_robot)). The issue is that WebotsController did not load the .yaml file for ros2_controllers.py successfully. It results in '/controller_manager' not exist. How can I fix this issue??
My current system:

- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- ROS humble
- Webots2023b

[image]

[image]